# Sudo command to become another user say "sa_hdpdm_qa"

Tags: linux

Let's say I am  the user xxx. I have been given permission to "sa_hdpdm_qa".

So, How to invoke a command to do **"sudo as sa_hdpdm_qa"**.

I am not sure about the commands. I searched online, but no luck..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u sa_hdpm_qa {command you want to execute}`
```

See also the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for sudo: the `-u` parameter is hard to overlook....

Comment: Hi there, I created a directory using the sudo command. Now, I need to execute "git init" command from the directory, but i am wondering How can i get into the directory. Sudo, does not work for "cd" command.

Comment: You can start an interactive `sudo` session using `sudo -u sa_hdpm_qa -i`. If the user in question doesn't have a shell set, try something along the lines of `sudo -u sa_hdpm_qa /bin/bash`, starting a shell with that users privileges.

Comment: @Jee - Try `sudo -u sa_hdpm_qa -s`. It will start a shell based on your `$SHELL`. Or just run `sudo -u sa_hdpm_qa git init /path/to/new`.